# ASP.Net MVC Razor - write tempdata in razor and retrieve from control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a single page with a Partial control on it called PartialContact

In reusing this control I would like to change the title within the PartialContact control. i.e.

```
        // change to Title1
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Contact1, "PartialContact")
        // change to Title2
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Contact2, "PartialContact")
        // change to Title3
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Contact3, "PartialContact")
```

Whats the best way to pass in title text within Razor? TempData?

(I have multiple different controls I need to do this with aswell)

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: Someone can write up a property answer. But if you just want a shortcut, use `ViewBag`. For a cleaner solution, use view models. i.e. Define a `ContactViewModel` which has a `Title` property, along with properties of your `Contact` that you want to expose. Then change `Contact1`..etc to point to `ContactViewModel`. And in your controller, you can set the `Title` when creating these view models.

Comment: Surely there another way to do this than creating another class for decoration? - I just want a title change? - Will try ViewBag now. If this is the only way I guess Ill do that -- Just was hoping there was another way I could pass a key/value bag aswell as the model to the control. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ViewDataDictionary to pass the value, e.g.

```
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Blah";
   Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Contact1, "PartialControl", ViewData);
}
```

Then access it in the partial with `@ViewData["Title"]`

Comment: Thanks I fixed it using the ViewContext.TempData  -- 
ViewContext.TempData["Heading"] = "Whatever";

Comment: Fair enough.  They are pretty much interchangeable, although TempData will last for two sequential requests so keep that in mind.